# TabHost not displaying

Tags: android

I have a problem while displaying a tabhost in my application. I tried any type of code. I know I have to call the tabwidget @android:id/tabs and other things like that but I still can't manage to show a tabbed view in my application. I need 4 tabs in it and I don't know how to do. Could you help me?????

As some of you wants code, here it is:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="this is a tab" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="this is another tab" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="this is a third tab" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the java:

```
TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

It is the code that i took from the link on the first answer.

Comment: Even we dont know what to answer. Please provide some code or mentions which error you are getting.

Comment: I don't have any code, I just tried with what I've found on internet

Comment: What you got so far? Can you show some code?

Comment: Don't expect that you ask question and people will write an app for you. Show what you got so far and we will try find mistake and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Before asking any question please make sure you try something and ask questions for whatever problem you face.
Try this [Hello World example](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)
I think this contains all required information.

Comment: I reversed google before asking, I tried everything but it's always the same. It simply doesn't work. Even this one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

call mTabHost.setup() before adding tabs.